# Equal, Not equal conditions on same field in single sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Following is schema of table called pages which is running on mysql 5.6 server

```
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| city          | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| email         | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I want to combine following 2 sql queries into single sql query, is this possible ??. I tried with nested queries but didn't get desired result.

```
select count(*) from pages where email != "";
select count(*) from pages where email = "";
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, you can write this very cleanly:

```
select sum(email <> "") not_blank, sum(email = "") blank from pages;
```

It uses the fact that true evaluates to 1 and false evaluates to 0 in MySQL.

In other DBMSes, equivalent query will be:

```
select sum(case when email <> "" then 1 else 0 end) not_blank,
    sum(case when email = "" then 1 else 0 end) blank
from pages;
```

If you want to use `COUNT`:

```
select count(case when email <> "" then 1 end) not_blank,
    count(case when email = "" then 1 end) blank
from pages;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even use a `CASE` expression.

**Query**

```
select 
  sum(case when trim(`email`) = "" or `email` is null then 1 else 0 end) `is_null`,
  sum(case when trim(`email`) <> "" or `email` is not null then 1 else 0 end) `is_not_null`
from `pages`;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(NOT_BLANK) NOT_BLANK,SUM(BLANK) BLANK FROM
(
select count(*) as NOT_BLANK,0 as BLANK from pages where email != "";
UNION ALL
select 0 as NOT_BLANK,count(*) as BLANK from pages where email = "";
)ZZ
```

Please try above code,hope this will help.